# Overloading an operation outside of a template classes

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

If I have a class with an overloaded assignment operator like this:

```
template<typename T> class Foo {
private:
     T var;
public:
    T operator=(T v){var = v;};
};
```

it works, but if I want to define the operator outside of the class it tells me `T` isn't a type (which it is are right about). How can I get around this and define it outside of the class?

Comment: `template<typename T>
T Foo<T>::operator=(T v)
{
    var = v;
}`

Comment: @sleeptightpupper Even if the OP keeps the return type as `T` instead of `Foo&` the implementation would need to return something.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. "it causes a fuss" is not sufficient information for us to diagnose what you did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You define it outside of the class as follows:

```
template<typename T>
Foo<T>& Foo<T>::operator=(T v)
// Note the Foo& that was added (it needs to be added to the declaration too)
// This is the idiomatic way to implement the assignment operator
{
    var = v;
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it return `Foo<T>&`?

Comment: @immibis Yes, of course. Good catch. Fixed the answer.